# Rewarding user for completing a task

Tags: flutter, dart, paypal, stripe-payments, payment

I am working on a new project where a user needs complete some given tasks for example lets consider the user needs to watch 10 rewarding video ads for getting rewarded back with $1
Which goes to his paypal wallet
So everytime he/she watches 10 videos he will be rewarded with a dollar how can i add this feature to my flutter app?

So what i have done is use a counter to count how many videos have been watched. After every video increase the count value and when it reaches 10 you call a function that sends 1 dollar to the user's account. After that, I reseted the counter value to 0. So my main problem is how can i send that 1$ to that user so that he can redeem to his wallet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use a counter to count how many videos have been watched. After every video increase the count value and when it reaches 10 you call a function that sends 1 dollar to the user's account. After that, you reset the counter to 0.

Comment: Yeah i got that already but my problem is how can i send that 1$ to that user so that he can redeem that to his paypal or any other wallet

Comment: for that, you will have to save the user's credentials and send the amount to his account. see more on the official Paypal website https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/

Comment: You need to create a rest API service